# How to use ng-if and ng-style together

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to match the height of a panel with the different height of individual angular-ui tabs. I tried to use ng-style by itself but it was not being triggered on the tabs "select". So I thought I could use a function to change the ng-style on the panel-body per individual tab but I am only able to get one style to be applied. 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ScyKAbnzdYWzs16S9Ax?p=preview)

```
  $scope.showSteps=function(){
        $scope.isOK=true;
        $scope.showStyle = 'height:482px';
      };   
$scope.showHowWorks=function(){
        $scope.isOK=true;
        $scope.showStyle = 'height:312px';
      };   
        $scope.showTerms=function(){
        $scope.isOK=true;
        $scope.showStyle = 'height:100px';
      };   
$scope.showYourself=function(){
        $scope.isOK=true;
        $scope.showStyle = 'height:600px';
      };
```

Html

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2 class="panel-title">Tabs</h2>
               </div>
         <div class="panel-body">
             <tabset justified="true">
                <tab heading="How It Works" select='showHowWorks()'>
                  <div>How It Works</div>
                </tab>
                <tab heading="Healthcare On Your Own Terms" select='showTerms()'>
                    <div>Healthcare On Your Own Terms</div>
                  </tab>
                <tab heading="Stay Healthy In 3 Steps" select='showSteps()'>
                     <div>Stay Healthy In 3 Steps</div>
                   </tab>
                <tab heading="Educate Yourself"  select='showYourself()'>
                   <div>EducateYourself</div>
                </tab>
              </tabset>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-lg-12">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-heading">
             <h2 class="panel-title">Column</h2>
           </div>
           <div class="panel-body" ng-if="isOK" ng-style="myStyle={{myStyle}}">
              <ul>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your show styles to this:

```
$scope.showStyle = { height: '482px' };
```

And then you can use it in your dom:

```
ng-style="showStyle"
```

Comment: so it was because i was using the expression in the ng-style?